# How to cast the key to int type in dictionary comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

Suppose I have two dictionaries

```
dict_a_to_c = {'803': 2, '808': 8, '30': 9, '37': 11, '38': 12, '39': 13, '481': 18, '816': 21, .....}
# length of dict_a_to_c is huge.
 
dict_a_to_b = {480:2, 37:5, 40: 9, 816:20, 148: 18}
```

And I am mapping them through keys using:

```
# converting key of dict_a_to_c to int
dict_a_to_c = {int(key):value for key, value in dict_a_to_c.items()}

dict_c_to_b = {dict_a_to_c[k]: dict_a_to_b[int(k)] for k in dict_a_to_b if k in dict_a_to_c}
```

Output of dict_c_to_b —> `{11: 5, 21: 20}`

But suppose if we want to cast the key to int type in the one line/logic of dict_c_to_b how can we do it in Python efficiently?

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the key _already_ an int?

Comment: @Chris They're asking how to do it **in one line**. It could be worded better, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Chris It is in `dict_a_to_b`, but not `dict_a_to_c`

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to str instead of to int:

```
dict_c_to_b = {dict_a_to_c[str(k)]: dict_a_to_b[k] 
    for k in dict_a_to_b if str(k) in dict_a_to_c}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand correctly:

```
dict_c_to_b = {k:dict_a_to_b[i] for v,k in dict_a_to_c.items()
               if (i:=int(v)) in dict_a_to_b}
```

output: `{11: 5, 21: 20}`

Comment: Yes, it's right, but not efficient. As we are iterating through dict_a_to_c which is larger in length than dict_a_to_b.

Comment: @yogesh I hadn't noticed the comment on the size (did you change that?), yes better loop on the small one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your last line to:

```py
dict_c_to_b = {
  dict_a_to_c[str(k)]: dict_a_to_b[k]
  for k in dict_a_to_b
  if str(k) in dict_a_to_c
}
```

And then there is no need to write the converting part!

Comment: [This solution has already been posted](/a/72888698/4518341) just a few minutes ago